# How can I correctly set a nested dict path for a json when querying

Tags: python, json, jsonq

I am getting the error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'Key not exists'
  File "C:\ShopFloor\main.py", line 59, in main
    res = qe.at('vehicledata.result.NUM').where('Status', '=', 1).where('Process', '=', 'SPA').get()
  File "C:\ShopFloor\main.py", line 96, in <module>
    main()
```

...in the following line:

```
qe = JsonQ(r"C:\ShopFloor\data.json")
res = qe.at('vehicledata.result.NUM').where('Status', '=', 1).where('Process', '=', 'SPA').get()      
pprint(res)
JsonQ.reset(qe)
```

vehicledata is a string however result.NUM is dynamic, as such there are about 2000 different dicts for result.NUM. My query is aiming at getting all nums where status is 1 and process is SPA: how can I get this to work? I'm thinking it's due to the dynamic dict any help is appreciated

Here is a small sample data from data.json

```
{
    "vehicledata": [
        {
            "12345678901234567": {
                "Process": "SPA",
                "Status": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "12345678901234567": {
                "Process": "Road",
                "Status": 0
            }
        },
```

Comment: Can you share the `data.json` and which fields you want to extract?

Comment: @DanielPryden its a json query package, ive found it really useful so far, here is a tutorial https://github.com/s1s1ty/py-jsonq#atpath

Comment: @Aaron_ab added a sample to q

Comment: Please add the exact error message you're getting to your post

Comment: @ForceBru added

Comment: @EcSync, "error message" means "the full traceback that's printed to your console". Please copy that whole message and add to your post

Comment: @EcSync Why should it work if you don't have `result.NUM` nested keys after you accessed `vehicledata`? (At least, based on the sample of data you provided)

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi result.NUM is dynamic, in the sample it reads as 12345678901234567 for example

Comment: @ForceBru added

Comment: You may not have control over the data but it's fairly inefficient to have dictionary with just one item. (Sadly web api query results all look like this.) A better structure would be putting the vehicle id (or whatever the long number is) as a separate entry along with status and process instead of having it as a key. Then, you will have a dict of list of dict, rather than dict of list of dict of dict. For that structure, JsonQ would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can just load it with json package and filter it that way.

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

curr_position = data['vehicledata']
result = [key for list_item in curr_position for key in list_item.keys() if list_item[key]['Status'] == 1 and list_item[key]['Process'] == 'SPA']
print(result)
```

According to the [jsonq docs](https://github.com/s1s1ty/py-jsonq#atpath), JsonQ does basically the same thing under the hood.

Comment: I like this method however I am getting the following error `Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [jsonq docs](https://github.com/s1s1ty/py-jsonq#atpath) sample you provided you need to change your code to the following:

```
from pyjsonq import JsonQ
from pprint import pprint
import json


qe = JsonQ("data.json")

res = qe.at('vehicledata').get()
l = list(map(lambda r: r.values()[0], res))
d = {"vehicledata": l}
with open('extarcted_data.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump(d, outfile)

q = JsonQ("extarcted_data.json")
r = q.at('vehicledata').where('Status', '=', 1).where('Process', '=', 'SPA').get()
print(r)

JsonQ.reset(q)
JsonQ.reset(qe)
```

The idea is the following you you take all the elements that can change between `vehicledata` and the object you need. Take the standard `json` library and wrap your previous object to the new one without extra-layer. After this use `JsonQ` for convenient search. The code above is the proof of concept and may be not the best solution. Based on the documentation `JsonQ` doesn't allow skip layers and you have to know your keys in order to retrieve data. In you case you would have to know `12345678901234567` or any number that would be instead of it.

**Alternative soltuon**

This solution makes usage of `JsonQ` doubtful. Nevertheless, I will post it here as a reference:

```
from pyjsonq import JsonQ
from pprint import pprint


qe = JsonQ("data.json")
objs = qe.at('vehicledata').get()

for obj in objs:
    values = obj.values()[0]
    if 'Status' in values and values['Status'] == 1 and 'Process' in values and values['Process'] == 'SPA':
        pprint(values)

JsonQ.reset(qe)
```

Comment: This is how it started off, it doesnt return any data...where did you unwrap the list in your answer?

Comment: running this returns [], i think this is becuase it cant access the nest and find the criteria i specified

Comment: @EcSync "unwrap" happens under `at` function after this you search each object for the specified criteria. What do you expect to return?

Comment: ah okay, it returns blanks, should come back with a couple of hundred results

Comment: @EcSync I modified my solution based on your comment. I don't think there is any good way to resolve this with exclusive usage of `JsonQ`, so I propose sort of "workarounds".